# Does a try affect functions called inside it in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, function, try-catch

I have some functions that I call inside a try. This try catches a KeyboardInterrupt. Currently the try doesn't affect the code executed by the functions that I call in it, and I was wondering if someone could help me.

I'm running python3 on a linux machine.

```py
import bar
def foo():
    try:
         bar.bar()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print("Interrupted")
```

In another file:

```py
    def bar():
        code...
```

But when I press ctrl+c the except doesn't execute.
If that code should execute, tell me and I'll post the code, I won't post it now beacusa it's a bit long.

I'd like the keyboard interrupt to be catched inside all the functions I call in the foo() try

Comment: This should work. Show a [mcve] of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
while trying to minimize the problem to post the code here I realized that the code was fine, but I was executing it from atom. I was using an atom package that on exception would close, therefore, the terminal closed every time.
Tho, the fact is that even if I included a class outside the function, I can't use it inside the except. So in my case I had to include again the class I wanted to use in the except.